# Is Dr. Mary Based or Inspired by Talk Show Radio Host Dr. Laura?

Tags: character, analysis, frasier

In the TV series ***Frasier***, a character **Dr. Mary** (Kim Coles) featured in two episodes, *Something About Dr. Mary* (7.16) and the season 8 Christmas episode, *Mary Christmas* (8.08), is a somewhat loadmouth talkshow radio host that is very popular and gets on Frasier's nerves. Is the character at all fashioned after or a satirical portrayal of the [at the time] famous [Dr. Laura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laura_Schlessinger) or another famous radio talk show host?

[image: Mary Christmas]

Answer (score 2):

If you mean [Dr. Laura Schlessinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laura_Schlessinger), then *probably* not, as she was parodied by the one-shot character [Dr. Nora](https://frasier.fandom.com/wiki/Dr._Nora) (played by Christine Baranski) from the episode of the same name.

Comment: Could you provide a source? That would be helpful. :)

Comment: @DarthLocke Dr Nora's fandom page has reference to Dr Laura https://frasier.fandom.com/wiki/Dr._Nora